# EditText: ввод цифр с преобразованием в формат "+7(XXX)XXX-XX-XX"

Tags: android, android-edittext

Достал вот этот блок

```
edTelData.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher() {
        //we need to know if the user is erasing or inputing some new character
        private boolean backspacingFlag = false;
        //we need to block the :afterTextChanges method to be called again after we just replaced the EditText text
        private boolean editedFlag = false;
        //we need to mark the cursor position and restore it after the edition
        private int cursorComplement;

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            //we store the cursor local relative to the end of the string in the EditText before the edition
            cursorComplement = s.length()-edTelData.getSelectionStart();
            //we check if the user ir inputing or erasing a character
            if (count > after) {
                backspacingFlag = true;
            } else {
                backspacingFlag = false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // nothing to do here =D
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String string = s.toString();
            //what matters are the phone digits beneath the mask, so we always work with a raw string with only digits
            String phone = string.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");

            //if the text was just edited, :afterTextChanged is called another time... so we need to verify the flag of edition
            //if the flag is false, this is a original user-typed entry. so we go on and do some magic
            if (!editedFlag) {

                //we start verifying the worst case, many characters mask need to be added
                //example: 999999999 <- 6+ digits already typed
                // masked: (999) 999-999
                if (phone.length() >= 7 && !backspacingFlag) {
                    //we will edit. next call on this textWatcher will be ignored
                    editedFlag = true;
                    //here is the core. we substring the raw digits and add the mask as convenient
                    String ans = "+7(" + phone.substring(1, 4) + ") " + phone.substring(4,7) + "-" + phone.substring(7);
                    edTelData.setText(ans);
                    //we deliver the cursor to its original position relative to the end of the string
                    edTelData.setSelection(edTelData.getText().length()-cursorComplement);

                    //we end at the most simple case, when just one character mask is needed
                    //example: 99999 <- 3+ digits already typed
                    // masked: (999) 99
                } else if (phone.length() >= 4 && !backspacingFlag) {
                    editedFlag = true;
                    String ans = "+7(" +phone.substring(1, 4) + ") " + phone.substring(4);
                    edTelData.setText(ans);
                    edTelData.setSelection(edTelData.getText().length()-cursorComplement);
                }
                // We just edited the field, ignoring this cicle of the watcher and getting ready for the next
            } else {
                editedFlag = false;
            }
        }
    });
```

сейчас, преобразует строку при вводе в формат

**+7(XXX)XXX-XXXX** 
Пожалуйста, помогите переделать в +7(XXX)XXX-XX-XX (добавить второе "-")

**ОБНОВЛЕНО**

Спасибо за ответы, теперь снизу **готовый исправленный код**(можно копи-пастить)

```
edTelData.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher() {
        //we need to know if the user is erasing or inputing some new character
        private boolean backspacingFlag = false;
        //we need to block the :afterTextChanges method to be called again after we just replaced the EditText text
        private boolean editedFlag = false;
        //we need to mark the cursor position and restore it after the edition
        private int cursorComplement;

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            //we store the cursor local relative to the end of the string in the EditText before the edition
            cursorComplement = s.length()-edTelData.getSelectionStart();
            //we check if the user ir inputing or erasing a character
            if (count > after) {
                backspacingFlag = true;
            } else {
                backspacingFlag = false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // nothing to do here =D
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String string = s.toString();
            //what matters are the phone digits beneath the mask, so we always work with a raw string with only digits
            String phone = string.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");

            //if the text was just edited, :afterTextChanged is called another time... so we need to verify the flag of edition
            //if the flag is false, this is a original user-typed entry. so we go on and do some magic
            if (!editedFlag) {

                //we start verifying the worst case, many characters mask need to be added
                //example: 999999999 <- 6+ digits already typed
                // masked: (999) 999-999
                if (phone.length() >= 9 && !backspacingFlag) {
                    //we will edit. next call on this textWatcher will be ignored
                    editedFlag = true;
                    //here is the core. we substring the raw digits and add the mask as convenient
                    String ans = "+7(" + phone.substring(1, 4) + ") " + phone.substring(4,7) + "-" + phone.substring(7,9) + "-" + phone.substring(9);
                    edTelData.setText(ans);
                    //we deliver the cursor to its original position relative to the end of the string
                    edTelData.setSelection(edTelData.getText().length()-cursorComplement);

                    //we end at the most simple case, when just one character mask is needed
                    //example: 99999 <- 3+ digits already typed
                    // masked: (999) 99
                } else if (phone.length() >= 4 && !backspacingFlag) {
                    editedFlag = true;
                    String ans = "+7(" +phone.substring(1, 4) + ") " + phone.substring(4);
                    edTelData.setText(ans);
                    edTelData.setSelection(edTelData.getText().length()-cursorComplement);
                }
                // We just edited the field, ignoring this cicle of the watcher and getting ready for the next
            } else {
                editedFlag = false;
            }
        }
    });
```

А это XML - код элемента:

```
<EditText
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/edTelNumber"
android:hint="Номер телефона"
android:gravity="center"
android:inputType="phone"
android:lines="1"
android:maxLength="17"
android:text="+7" />
```

Comment: у вас могут возникнуть проблемы,если пользователь решит вводить номер не с 8, а с 9, например, 9010102032, тогда у вас первая цифра "съедается", можно немного изменить код на этот случай : 
`else if (phone.length() >= 4 && !backspacingFlag && !string.contains("+7")) {
                editedFlag = true;
                String ans = "+7(" + phone.substring(0, 3) + ") " + phone.substring(3);
                mEditText.setText(ans);
                mEditText.setSelection(mEditText.getText().length() - cursorComplement);
            }`

Comment: @Сергей, ну не знаю. Если в поле +7 уже есть, ничего не съедается, если поле пустое, обычно в России пишут через 8(код страны всегда пишут), а так как этот блок для российских приложений используется, то это необдуманно - писать через 9, например. И спасибо за доработку! Это важное замечание

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Изменить условие `if (phone.length() >= 7 && !backspacingFlag)` на `if (phone.length() >= 9 && !backspacingFlag)` и

```
String ans = "+7(" + phone.substring(1, 4) + ") " + phone.substring(4,7) + "-" + phone.substring(7);
```

Изменить на:

```
String ans = "+7(" + phone.substring(1, 4) + ") " + phone.substring(4,7) + "-" + phone.substring(7,9) + "-" + phone.substring(9);
```

Comment: Мне кажется, в конце должно быть: + "-" + phone.substring(7,9) + "-" + phone.substring(9);

Comment: @iFr0z, второе тире появилось, однако ваша строка обрезает последний символ и добавляет введённые ранее цифры ещё раз. Проверьте, пожалуйста

Comment: @iFr0z, c 7-кой в условии выдало 
`java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=7; regionStart=7; regionLength=2`

Comment: @zayn1991 а теперь все работает прекрасно?)

Comment: @iramm спасибо, не заметил)

Comment: @iFr0z, да, отлично =)

Comment: @zayn1991 рады были помочь)

Answer (score 0):

Есть небольшой косяк если стереть все и начать писать заново.

Лечится проверкой на +7

```
if (phone.length() >= 4 && !backspacingFlag) {
  editedFlag = true;
  String beg=string.substring(0, 2);
  if ("+7".equals(beg)) {
   String ans = "+7(" + phone.substring(1, 4) + ") " + phone.substring(4);
   mEditTextPassword.setText(ans);
   mEditTextPassword.setSelection(mEditTextPassword.getText().length() - cursorComplement);} 
  else {
   String ans = "+7(" + phone.substring(0, 3) + ") " + phone.substring(3);
   mEditTextPassword.setText(ans);
   mEditTextPassword.setSelection(mEditTextPassword.getText().length() - cursorComplement);
   }
  }
```

Comment: сейчас это проверю

Comment: Ваш код не подойдёт тем, кто захочет стереть всё и начать писать с 8-ки. 
У меня, если в пустом поле вводить с 89991112233, переведётся в +7(999)1112233, потому что многие интуитивно пишут с 8-ки